# Find anomaly in a series of numbers

Tags: c#

I have list of numbers

```
var nums = new List<double> {1,2,2.4,2.6,1.5,3,1.9};
```

The items of the list are assumed to be distributed *normally*; in the such series I want to filter out *anomalies* (which can be `1` and `3` since they seems to be the *most deviated values*). I have to work with dynamic series and their values may change, so can't hard code any value in a condition check.

Comment: anything you have tried so far?

Comment: Define "anomaly"

Comment: And why the `1.5` isn't an anomaly as well? I would think that 1.5 and 1.9 are odd, since rest would be sorted ascending without them. How do you **know** what is an anomaly and what is ok?

Comment: What is the logic you applied which says "3" is an anomaly? Unless I understand that not sure if I will be able to help

Comment: `1` is further from the other values than `3` is, so would that be an anomaly as well?

Comment: 3 is out of normal range the more a range appears it will become normal else it has to be filtered out.

Comment: You can do this by calculating the standard deviation http://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-deviation.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the distribution of `nums` items is assumed to be *normal* one, we can treat a value being anomaly if it's beyond `[mean - k * sigma..mean + k * sigma]` range (`sigma` stands for the standard deviation), where `k` is typically `2` (95%), `3` (99.76%), sometimes even `5`.
If it's your case, you can implement

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Anomaly<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, 
                                        Func<T, double> map, 
                                        double maxSigma = 3.0) {
  if (null == source)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
  else if (null == map)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("map");

  T[] data = source.ToArray();

  if (data.Length <= 1)
    yield break;

  double s = 0.0;
  double s2 = 0.0;

  foreach (var item in data) {
    double x = map(item);

    s += x;
    s2 += x * x;
  }

  double mean = s / data.Length;
  double sigma = Math.Sqrt(s2 / data.Length - (s / data.Length) * (s / data.Length));
  double leftMargin = mean - maxSigma * sigma;
  double rightMargin = mean + maxSigma * sigma;

  foreach (var item in data) {
    double x = map(item);

    if (x < leftMargin || x > rightMargin)
      yield return item;
  }
}
```

And so you can find anomalies for different `k`:

```
var nums = new List<double> { 1, 2, 2.4, 2.6, 1.5, 3, 1.9 };

// k = 3 (typical criterium of 3 sigma deviation - 99.76%) -  empty output
Console.Write(string.Join(", ", Anomaly(nums, x => x, 3)));

// k = 1 (unusual criterium of just 1 sigma deviation - 67%) the output is "1, 3"
Console.Write(string.Join(", ", Anomaly(nums, x => x, 1)));
```

Comment: Okay, NOW I understand what the OP meant...

Comment: @Nebr: for some questions crystal ball is indispensable... and I have to confess that I have an unfair advantage: my current project is anomaly detection in one telecom database.

Answer (score -1):

A very general answer to your request: You need to define what an anomaly is. This is your predicate. Then filter the list with respect to the predicate.

```
var nums = new List<double> {1,2,2.4,2.6,1.5,3,1.9};
Predicate<double> anomalyPredicate = IsNoAnomaly; // Definition of a predicate
List<double> listWithoutAnomalies= nums.FindAll(anomalyPredicate); // Find every item that is not an anomaly
```

Let's assume that the anomaly is that the number is 3 or larger. Then you have:

```
private static bool IsNoAnomaly(double d)
{
    return d < 3;
}
```

But of course, IsNoAnomaly may be any bool returning function.

**Edit:** Another example: If there is a threshold _currentThreshold determined at run-time which may not be reached or exceeded, the function would be:

```
private static bool IsNoAnomaly(double d)
{
    return d < _currentThreshold;
}
```

Comment: This should be done without specifying a filter value.

Comment: It can be. Just fill in what you need it to be. Instead of d < 3, write whatever you need, it was just an example. If the filter is of variable value, write d < _currentFilterValue or whatever.

Comment: In my case there will be range of values, We don't know which is going to be threshold.Its completly dynamic.

Comment: But you need to know the algorithm to determine if something is inside the range. The algorithm itself can't be dynamic.